# How to get different "modules" from modules table?

Tags: mysql

I have "moduller" table in that table keeping modules of system with function name. Two information in one field. Like this:

[image]

Slug field mean is like this: "MODULE_NAME/function_name"

I want to get the list:
 1. admin
 2. ajax
 3. analysisusers
 4. bonus

How to get i'm only different modules names like above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the position of the `/` character, take everything left of it, then do `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(slug,LOCATE('/',slug) - 1) module_name
FROM moduller WHERE LOCATE('/',slug) > 0;
```

Comment: I have solved the problem similar way:
select DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(slug, '/', 1) as slugx from crm_moduller;